# Visitor design pattern for enums

Tags: java, design-patterns

I receive from a client a Response of a given parameter-type and hex-value. Based on the parameter-type I know what type of parameter it refers and I could build the specific Parameter.

I would like to find a design pattern that allows me to get rid of the explicit parameter-type check:

```
if (paramType != reponse.paramType)
```

Also I would like to be protected by a compiler error, when in future we add a new ParameterType the response-parameter parser is not missed.

I thought to use the Visitor design pattern, but I believe it is not going to work because ParameterType is a enum.

Model:

```
enum ParameterType {
    NAME, 
    PHOTO,
    ...
    ;
}

class Response {
    ParameterType paramType;
    String value;
}

interface IParameter {}
 
class ParameterName implements IParameter {
    static ParameterType paramType = ParameterType.NAME;
    ParameterName fromReponse(response) {
        if (paramType != reponse.paramType) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return parse(response);
    }
    ParameterName parse();
}

class ParameterPhoto implements IParameter  { 
    static ParameterType paramType = ParameterType.PHOTO;
    ParameterPhoto fromReponse(response) {
        if (paramType != reponse.paramType) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return parse(response);
    }
    ParameterPhoto parse();
}   

...
```

Service:

```
ParameterName getParameterName() {
    var response = client.getName();
    var param = ParameterName.fromResponse(response);
    return param;
}

ParameterPhoto getParameterPhoto() {
    var response = client.getPhoto();
    var param = ParameterPhoto.fromResponse(response);
    return param;
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean way would be to make one response-object per request like you already have, and then make the request-method parse the response-data into your response-object and return it. Then there is no need for a *ParameterType* enum.

```
class Client{
  ParameterName getName(){
      Object responseData = // whatever call you execute to retrieve your name data
      ParameterName result = // parse name from responseData
      return result;
  }

  ParameterPhoto getPhoto(){
      Object responseData = // whatever call you execute to retrieve your photo data
      ParameterPhoto result = // parse photo from responseData
      return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Visitor pattern here.

What you need is the Factory pattern:

```
class ParameterFactory {
 public static IParameter getInstance(ParameterType paramType) {
   //Can use switch here if more options
   if (paramType==ParameterType.NAME) {
     return new NameParameter();
   } else {
     return new PhotoParameter();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple parameter types, and might be more in future. I am looking for a way, when I will add a new ParameterType, the compiler will warn if I miss the new Parameter impl. I'm not sure a if chain, or long switch, d be a good solution.

Comment: `switch` is the only way to give you an error if you miss the new param impl out of the box. You can throw an error in the `default` branch

Comment: Note the factory example here is specifically a [Static Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info), not to be confused with the GoF patterns.